# How to build a BallTree with haversine distance metric?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distance, haversine

I have been studying how to implement a `sklearn.neighbors.BallTree` with  `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances` metric.

Despite my efforts, I couldn't reach a working script.

Despite the standard example from the sklearn documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html), when one attempts to use the haversine distance metric within the BallTree, the whole initialization of the class breaks into a ValueError. See below a simple script that results in this problem:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
X = rng.random_sample((10, 2))  # 10 points in 2 dimensions
tree = BallTree(X, metric=metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances)
```

Returned error:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 2, got 1)
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `metric="haversine"`. From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) (emphasis in the original):

> **Note: Callable functions in the metric parameter are NOT supported for KDTree
> and Ball Tree. Function call overhead will result in very poor performance.**

See also the documentation on [distance_metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.distance_metrics.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.distance_metrics).

Comment: Dear Ben Reiniger, thank you for your reply. Based on the sklearn's documentation, I automatically assumed that the string "haversine" would result in the sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances implementation. As it seems, it is not the case. I will try the string approach, the. Sincerely

Comment: Dear Ben Reiniger, thank you for your feedback. Your solution worked wonderfully. Sincerely,